# Get Response Data in XML format

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

We use `JSON.stringify(oData);` to get data in json, and how could we get data in the form of xml?

```
oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse){
    var data = JSON.stringify(oData);
    document.write(data );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an OData service, but you're wanting the response in a certain format. That can only mean, to me, that you're wanting to bypass all the work that the ODataModel mechanism does for you and get the raw XML that is returned by the OData server. If that is the case, I have a question and an answer for you.

Question: Why?

Answer: If you really want to get the XML from the OData response, i.e. the raw Atom feed that typically comes back from, say, a Northwind entityset like http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products , then you can actually access the whole HTTP response object in the success callback of the read() method. Extending the source code in your question a bit, it would look like this:

```
oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse){
    document.write(oResponse.body);
});
```

This will produce something like this:

```
<feed xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products</id>
<title type="text">Products</title>
<updated>2014-08-26T07:33:36Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="Products" href="Products"/>
<entry>
<id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products(1)</id>
...
```

But - are you sure you really want this?

Answer (score 0):

To get XML formatted response, add $format=xml to your odata url

See example :

1. http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$format=json
2. http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$format=xml

And to get response in XML format, use the `sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel`

```
oModel.read('/?$format=xml', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse){
    var xmlDataModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel(oData);    
});
```

Comment: I get this "EventProvider sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel" when I put var xmlDataModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel(oData);

Comment: No I didn't get it. The data coming from server is already xml. But am not able to get using   var xmlDataModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel(oData);